# Which is the best managed .NET e-mail component with support for S/MIME?

Tags: .net, email, smtp, components, smime

I need a replacement for `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` that is able to send signed and/or encrypted e-mails.

Is there an open source library covering that?

Or do you have some experiences with some of those:

- [Chilkat Mail](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/mime-dotnet.asp)
- [Easymail](http://www.quicksoftcorp.com/emdotnet/)
- [Dart Mail for .NET](http://www.dart.com/ptmlnet.aspx?source=adwords&gclid=CO7lrbCpzZkCFQMEZgody0ZKtw)
- You got more?

Comment: I guess you are talking about .Net, but you might want to make that a little more explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you *can* in fact send S/MIME encrypted emails using the BCL of .NET. It requires a bit of a hack (not too bad however), but you could wrap the solution easy enough... See [this MSDN forum thread](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/74e4711e-1f66-43a7-9e3b-bc9cfbcd1b73/) and possibly also [this one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ncl/thread/ca93b37d-b8ad-4793-96a5-46d663c6cfad). Note that an example is additionally provided for [Rebex Secure Mail](http://www.rebex.net/secure-mail.net/), a commercial product, if you're having no luck with the BCL solution. Saying that, I would definitely recommend using the solution provided in the System.Net namespace if at all possible, despite requiring a bit of custom configuration.

Answer (score -1):

[MIMEBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-mime.php) is the most feature-rich component set for MIME, S/MIME and PGP/MIME.